# Removing duplicates out of multiple arrays, php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got multiple arrays, and want to remove the duplicates. So I only got the unique items.

```
array(4) {
 [0]=>
  string(14) "Bergen op Zoom"
 [1]=>
  string(9) "jan steen"
 [2]=>
  string(7) "culture"
 [3]=>
  string(11) "Netherlands"
}

array(8) {
 [0]=>
  string(14) "fasion"
 [1]=>
  string(9) "conceptial"
 [2]=>
  string(7) "industrial"
 [3]=>
  string(11) "Netherlands"
}
```

I want to print all the strings out of the array except for the last Netherlands because it's already printed.

I've tried it with `array_unique()` but it only does that if there are duplicates in the array itself.

no clue how to get this thing working..

Comment: Its pretty unclear can you please post your expected output

Comment: the output needs to be: Bergen op zoom, jan steen, culture, Netherlands , fasion, conceptial, industrial. so the second 'Netherlands' needs to be removed somehow

Comment: *except for the last Netherlands because it's already printed* - ?

Comment: both arrays have 'Netherlands' in it, But I want to print it only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
array_unique( array_merge($array1, $array2) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Use array_diff. It will stay in arr1 only items that not in arr2

```
array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: The problem with this is I don't know how many arrays there are going to be

Comment: You can repeat using array_diff with every new array.

Comment: If anyone is interested, `array_diff_key()` does the same for array keys rather than values.

Comment: This is not  suitable for `array_diff_key` function @jonbaldie

Comment: Good One might be late for answering @splash58 +1

Comment: I'm using an API that gives me the arrays, could be 2, could be 5 or way more.

Comment: @Floes let's understand. You want remove already printed values, which in that arrays, from the first one? Or want to receive list of unique values of all arrays?

Comment: I want to get the full list of uniqe values, The arrays are stored in $projectData->tags. for now that are 4 arrays.

Comment: @Floes Then you can use answer of SenthilVel, because i misread your question and my solution loose  the 'Netherlands'